# Compare two files and print only the first word of the lines which don't match along with a string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I want to compare two files and print only the first word of the lines that match and that don't match along with a string.

```
file1.txt
=========

abc 123
bcd 234
cde 345

file2.txt
=========

abc 123
bcd 223
cde 234
```

above abc is matching in both file1.txt and file2.txt. So I need to print as below:

```
abc is matching. it is ok.
```

above bcd and cde in file1.txt and file2.txt are not different. So I need to print as below:

```
bcd is not matching. please check.
cde is not matching. please check.
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am new to scripting and learning things. I tried by using the solutions provided by other users in this forum for other similar questions but could not proceed beyond displaying the first word.

Comment: And Jeff. I now understood from your question it would be helpful if I mentioned what was done and where I was stuck. I'll surely follow this going forward.

Comment: Sounds good, and welcome to U&L stack exchange! Some of us like to see an effort to a point where you get stuck; others like to solve the problem on their own. Just something to be aware of going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}; $2==a[$1] {print $1 " OK"; next} \
                                        {print $1 " Not OK"}' f1.txt f2.txt
```

- `NR==FNR` is true for only the first file, `f1.txt` here; we are creating array `a` with the first field as the key and the second field as the value, `next` goes to the next record without moving further down the conditionals
- `$2==a[$1]` checks if the second field of the second file, `f2.txt` matches the values of the key first field of the array `a`, and then printing in desired format

**Example:**

```
% cat f1.txt
abc 123
bcd 234
cde 345

% cat f2.txt
abc 123
bcd 223
cde 234

% awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}; $2==a[$1] {print $1 " OK"; next} {print $1 " Not OK"}' f1.txt f2.txt
abc OK
bcd Not OK
cde Not OK
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help on this. It is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[NR]=$0;next}{if($0==A[FNR]){print $0 "is matching. it is ok"}else{print $0 "is not matching. please check"}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

readable format

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
A[NR]=$0;
next
}
{
if($0==A[FNR])
{
    print $0 "is matching. it is ok"
}
else{
print $0 "is not matching. please check"
}
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Kamaraj thank you for your time and help. I tried with your code, but it is giving the entire line along the string that we wish to add to it. @heemayl example is giving the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

the code @ Kamaraj has been updated.
Please  you need replace the the lines :

```
print $0 "is matching. it is ok"
print $0 "is not matching. please check"
```

by

```
split($0,a,/ /); print a[1] " is matching. it is ok"
split($0,a,/ /);print a[1] " is not matching. please check"
```

or 
    print $1 "is matching. it is ok"
    print $1 "is not matching. please check"

All the script will be :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
A[NR]=$0;
next
}
{
if($0==A[FNR])
{
split($0,a,/ /); print a[1] " is matching. it is ok"
}
else{
split($0,a,/ /);print a[1] " is not matching. please check"
}
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

TIMES:

@heemayl
real    0m0.159s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.046s

@Kamaraj
real    0m0.102s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s with *split*

**@Kamaraj
real    0m0.099s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.062s** with *$1*

Thanks @Kamaraj.

Comment: no need to use the split. instead $0, we can use $1

Comment: Solution With Performance. Thanks @Kamaraj. Need to check code though. :)